# VIM syntax highlight matching

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that C++ functions were not getting any styles applied to them with my vim stylings, so I figured it'd be simple to add a quick regex match to find any word immediately followed by a (, and count that as a syntax.

In my .vim, I put:

```
syn match cppFun "\w+(?=\()"
```

This appears to work fine with [other regex matchers](https://regex101.com/r/RuKb43/1), but vim complained about an unmatching `\)`.
However, checking `:highlight`, I did see the syntax cppFun was getting something set to it.

I figured that maybe the vim regex was backwards, and so I tried this out

```
syn match cppFun "\w+\(?=(\)"
```

And while it no longer complained about an unmatching paren, I was getting still not getting function highlights in my main.cpp.

What should the regex look like in order to get the syntax highlighting showing up?

This is what I was testing against with `\w+(?=\()`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::puts('Hello World');
    return 0;
}
```

Expecting to match `main` and `puts`

Comment: Try this: `syntax match cppFun "\v\w+\s*\([^)]*\)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a word followed by a `(` without matching the `(`, use `\w\+\ze(`.

The `\ze` terminates the matching part of the regex. The `+` needs to be prepended with a `\` to make it magic. (See [:help magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic)).

Also [positive lookahead](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind) in vim is done with `\@=`. Not with `(?=...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```js
\v\w+(\()@=
```

**Details**

- `\v` - enables the very magic mode when quantifiers and capturing/lookaround parentheses do not need backslash-escaping
- `\w+` - one or more word characters (letters, digits, underscores)
- `(\()@=` - a positive lookahead (`(...)@=`) that requires its pattern (here, a `(` char) to match immediately to the right of the current location.